# Capture full trace of HTTPS protocol in firefox/chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, https, sniffing

When I make a request in a browser like firefox or chrome, I would like to view a full trace of the HTTPS protocol, including the http version negotiation, the TLS negotiation, the headers, etc. The network tab of the browser only seems to show the request and response headers. This would look similar to using curl with the verbose -v option.

I am open to any reasonably simple solution, such as a addon or an external tool. I know that man-in-the-middle sniffers exist, but it seems to me that they would not give me the exact trace because the https negotiation between the sniffer and the destination might be slightly different.

Comment: Unfortunately the only layer that gets to see both the unencrypted HTTP headers and the TLS negotiation is the TLS code itself. A packet sniffer will only see Ethernet, IP, TCP, and TLS stuff and will not be able to decrypt the TLS packets to see the HTTP headers. And as you said, the browsers dev tools just show you the HTTP headers but not what the TLS stuff looked like.

I don't know if the TLS libraries used by Firefox and Chrome have debug options to log both the HTTP cleartext and the TLS negotiation and ciphertext.

You might have to use a packet sniffer plus the browser dev tools.

Comment: `curl -v` _sometimes_ (depending on stack) shows the TLS handshake message codes; this is nowhere near a full trace. It does show full HTTP (request and response), as does browser. @Spiff: both Firefox and Chrome support SSLKEYLOGFILE to write out the _session key info_ which Wireshark (for one) can use to decrypt a packet capture: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199903/ https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103843/ https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80158/ https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64814/ https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35639/